# Do we need to check normality of the residuals when using 'CSS' method to fit ARIMA model?

Tags: estimation, arima, normality-assumption

I'm using `auto.arima` to fit my model. When I used the default `CSS-ML` method, I noticed that the residuals are not normal. So I want to use a method that doesn't require the normality assumption. I'm guessing CSS would work, since the method simply tries to minimize SSE but I'm not quite sure. If I use `method='CSS'` with `auto.arima`, do I still need to check for the normality of the error term with residuals?

I've tried a lot of different transformations so that the residuals can be tested as normal with `jarque.bera.test` or `shapiro.test`, but it didn't really work. The prediction results are good, Ljung-Box test shows that there is no problem with using the model, yet the normality condition isn't being satisfied. So I just want to try other approaches where normality doesn't really matter.

Comment: Could you try bootstrapping your forecasts? It seems like potentially a good way to get rid of the need for a normality assumption.

Comment: Check out [these threads](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arima+normality-assumption), e.g. comments in [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/143073/non-normal-residuals-in-arima). Your question might be a duplicate of one of these.

Comment: I checked out the comments and what prof rob hyndman said. And I actually observed that with my data, the output of method='CSS' and method = 'CSS-ML' is almost exactly the same. So I guess it is not that critical that normality assumption isn't being satisfied in this case? Am I understanding it correctly?

Comment: I cannot answer this definitively, as I am not sure myself. But since the ML implementation is based on an assumption of normality, it is no wonder that CSS and CSS-ML give nearly identical results.